# Installing LXD Stucks

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-18.04, lxd

I upgraded my ubuntu version from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04 focal. After reboot, I was asked to install upgrades. But when I do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The seconds command exits with error telling I need install lxd. But installing LXD doesn't work, it has been an hour since it shows below message. What is the problem?? how to fix it??

```
root@apulis-dev-infra02:~# apt-get install lxd
The following packages will be upgraded:
lxd
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1089 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,108 B of archives.
After this operation, 20.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 250517 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/lxd_1%3a0.7_all.deb ...
=> Installing the LXD snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the LXD snap from the 3.0 track for ubuntu-20.04
2020-01-09T17:24:52+08:00 INFO Waiting for restart...
```

Comment: Do you know if the `Waiting for restart` message means it wants you to restart the computer?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I thought it would restart by it self, and was worried if I restarted the computer its work would be corrupted.